# How to call block without controller in phtml?

Tags: magento2

How to call block without controller in phtml file for my custom module in magento2??

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View');
```

I'm not really sure if this is what you are after, your question is a little on the short side.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$blockObj= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View');
```

Comment: use $this  instant of $block